# I look for the open source Web application that used ZendFramework

Tags: php, zend-framework

I found "dodo".
Please　give me informations with it if You know it besides it.

Answer (score 2):

The probably most "well known" is [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) ; it is an open-source e-commerce platform, developped by [Varien](http://www.varien.com/).

You might also want to take a look at these pages on Zend's website :

- [Case Studies](http://framework.zend.com/about/casestudies) : it gives a list of a couple of big companies that choose using Zend Framework
- And, if your goal is to say "Zed Framework is something solid, not a small little project", it can be useful to know ZF has [partnerships with big companies](http://framework.zend.com/community/partners) too.

Comment: Worth noting that Magento uses its own MVC system, not the `Zend_Controller` components.

Comment: How ; good to know, indeed (I've never used it yet ; but it might come, as some colleagues are working with it ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.ZFCounter.org